# Detect if a github pull-request on json file is valid?

Tags: automation, git, github

I've noticed some github repos have an automated process for validating files on pull requests.

For example say there is a JSON file that recieves a pull request. I'd like a setup where the new file is checked against a validation script. Then the bot would respond as a comment saying if the test was passed or not.

Here is a [repo which seems to use a similar process](https://github.com/Kickball/awesome-selfhosted/pull/975).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the [Github](https://github.com/) hook [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/).  The basics are explained [HERE](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

> Webhooks allow you to build or set up integrations which subscribe to certain events on GitHub.com. When one of those events is triggered, we'll send a HTTP POST payload to the webhook's configured URL. Webhooks can be used to update an external issue tracker, trigger CI builds, update a backup mirror, or even deploy to your production server. You're only limited by your imagination.